# APOC plugin for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I tried to install APOC plugin for my Ubuntu VBox.

Neo4j version: 3.3.1

Downloaded the JAR: `apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar`

and placed it into `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`

Restarted the server but calling `RETURN apoc.verison()` prompts me:

`Unknown function 'apoc.version' (line 1, column 8 (offset: 7))
"RETURN apoc.version()"
        ^`

Seems the APOC plugin is not registered. What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**: I did a full reload of my VirtualBox (halt and then up), and then start the Neo4j. The APOC plugin now works fine.

I am using a 1604 Ubuntu Virtual Box.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Does `call apoc.help("")` work? Or does `call dbms.procedures()` lists the apoc procedures?

Comment: Neither works or show APOC procedures.

Comment: Can you give me the result of this query `call dbms.listConfig("dbms.directories.plugins") YIELD value`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on macOS Sierra, Neo4j Desktop 1.0.21. Ymmv.

Assuming you've got the APOC .jar…

- Select your project
- Click the `Manage` button for your database
- Click the `Open Folder` button
- Move the .jar into the `plugins` folder

Here are those same steps presented visually:

[image]

[image]

[image]